# GAE channel api

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, sockets, channel

I am building a chat app with the channel api (java backend - javascript frontend). each time a user gets a username, it is listed in remaining users screen. the new user is sent to each of the users from the channel and will be displayed. but i want to remove the users from the list if they close the window. i actually wonder how to recognize if a user closed his window or not with the channel api?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the channel API that would need to do this directly; in JavaScript you can use `onunload` to determine when the user navigates away from the page, then trigger the channel API as you normally would.  However, there's no guarantee that it will get called (think of what would happen if I just hard power-off my machine).  You can use JavaScript to provide a heartbeat and implement logic on the server to say "if I haven't heard anything from the client in X seconds/minutes/whatever, then consider this user's session closed."

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing on python. All you need to do is to enable the [presence](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview#Tracking_Client_Connections_and_Disconnections) inbound service and then's you'll be receiving requests on /_ah/channel/disconnected/ whenever a client get's disconnected. From the request params you can determine who the client was and send remove him from the application's users' list (if one exists) and (if necessary) send a channel message to the remaining clients to also remove him from the list they see on the